# Visual Studio 2015 Copy and Paste Project and all dll files missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, project, copy-paste

After i copy and paste my c# visual studio 2015 project  to other directory, Copied project's dlls are all missing.

original project is in C:\test\temp1 , and ccopied project is in C:\test\temp2

when i remove all dll and add new dll, project cant recognize dll file. 
How can i restore this dll ?

[image]

**update :
This is dll property. how can i check  relative or absolute path?

[image]

Comment: check the dll locations in your source project and see whether it is relative or absolute path.

Comment: You seem to have problems with **all** your assembly references not just the one to your DLLs.  Are you sure your project settings is the same?  .NET version for example?

Comment: @Lei Yang How can i check dll path is relative or absolute ?

Comment: @MickyD I set my project setting is same as original project.

Comment: select dll- right click - properties

Comment: @Lei Yang update my question. i don't know where can i check relative or absolute path on dll property

Answer (score 0):

I think you must replace it one by one.

**Step 1:**
Right click the reference.

**Step 2:**
Add new reference.

**Step 3:**
Find the missing reference and Add it.

**Note**
Delete first the error reference before adding new.
This is only a suggestion.
Good luck

Comment: What you got? Same problem?

Comment: @ Richard Baluyut Yes. I remove missing dll and add from Assemblies (like WindowsBase). But missing mark was still appeared